# How show the data in UILabel from a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "SQLClient.h"
 @interface mgrViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
 SQLClientDelegate>{ 
     NSMutableArray *pajaros;
 }
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *miTabla;
 @property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *pajaros;
 @end
```

And in my .m file:

```
#import "mgrViewController.h"
#import "Vista2.h"
#import "SQLClient.h"
@interface mgrViewController ()
@end

@implementation mgrViewController
@synthesize miTabla;
@synthesize pajaros;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
client.delegate = self;
[client connect:@"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx" username:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" password:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx" database:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" completion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success)
    {    
       pajaros =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [client execute:@"SELECT field FROM table WHERE field='xxxxxxxxx'" completion:^(NSArray* results) {          
               NSMutableString* resulta = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                for (NSArray* table in results)
                    for (NSDictionary* row in table)
                        for (NSString* column in row){
                            //[results appendFormat:@"\n%@ = %@", column, row[column]];
                            [resulta appendFormat:@"\n%@", row[column]];
                            [pajaros addObject:resulta];
                        }
            [client disconnect];
        }];
    }
}];
self.miTabla.delegate = self;
self.miTabla.dataSource = self;
}

 #pragma mark - SQLClientDelegate

- (void)error:(NSString*)error code:(int)code severity:(int)severity
{
    NSLog(@"Error #%d: %@ (Severity %d)", code, error, severity);
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}

- (void)message:(NSString*)message
{
    NSLog(@"Message: %@", message);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return pajaros.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celdaPajaros";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // elementos que contienen cada celda con sus tags
    UILabel *labelTitulo = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:10];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    labelTitulo.text = [pajaros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 70.f;
}
@end
```

If I add a count for my NSMutableArray `pajaros` after the line of code `[pajaros addObject:resulta];`and I print that count, the result is 1, because my conditional where is for select a data. But if put a count in other part of my code, the result is 0.

My question is how I retain the data in my NSMutableArray for use in:

```
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return pajaros.count;
    }
```

and in:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celdaPajaros";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // elementos que contienen cada celda con sus tags
        UILabel *labelTitulo = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:10];

        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        labelTitulo.text = [pajaros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

?

Thanks for the help, I'm new in Objective-C.

If I initialize `pajaros` with a data in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pajaros = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bird1", nil];
    self.miTabla.delegate = self;
    self.miTabla.dataSource = self;
    }
```

And run my app, the labelTitulo show me Bird1. My second question is: why when I add data to my `NSMutableArray pajaros` from a Data Base and run my app, it's show me nothing?

Thanks.

Comment: You seems to use ARC, in ARC you don't have to mind about memory retain/release.

Comment: Thanks, but how I retain the data in my NSMutableArray? My knowledge about ARC is basic.

Answer (score 0):

When using properties, it's best to include `self.`.  Try `self.pajaros = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` and likewise in the other places where you just use `pajaros`.

Comment: Thanks, I try using `self` in each line of code with `NSMutableArray pajaros`, but the result is the same that before I used `self`. If I will be use `self` only in some lines of code with `NSMutableArray pajaros`tell me please.

Comment: Try using NSLog() to print the value of self.pajaros when its count is 1 and again when its count is 0.  I'd be interested in knowing whether the addresses are the same.

Comment: I use `self.textView.text = [self.pajaros objectAtIndex:0];`in the block of code where the count show me 1 and in the block of code where the count show me 0, in the first case the app show me the data, and the second case the app show me nothing. I edited my question and I add another question. Thanks.